# Allow/require only one record with common FK to have "primary" flag

Tags: mysql, triggers, unique-index

Firstly, I apologise if this is a dupe - I suspect it may be but I can't find it.

Say I have a table of companies:

```
 id | company_name
----+--------------
  1 | Someone
  2 | Someone else
```

...and a table of contacts:

```
 id | company_id | contact_name | is_primary
----+------------+--------------+------------
  1 |     1      | Tom          |      1
  2 |     2      | Dick         |      1
  3 |     1      | Harry        |      0
  4 |     1      | Bob          |      0
```

Is it possible to set up the `contacts` table in such a way that it *requires* that one and only one record has the `is_primary` flag set for each common `company_id`?

So if I tried to do:

```
UPDATE contacts
SET is_primary = 1
WHERE id = 4
```

...the query would fail, because `Tom` (`id = 1`) is already flagged as the primary contact for `company_id = 1`. Or even better, would it be possible to construct a trigger so that the query would succeed, but `Tom`'s `is_primary` flag would be cleared by the same operation?

I am not too bothered about checking whether `company_id` exists in the `companies` table, my PHP code would already have performed this check before I got to this stage (although if there is a way to do this in the same operation it would be nice, I suppose).

When I initially thought about this I thought "that will be easy, I'll just add a unique index across the `company_id` and `is_primary` columns" but obviously that won't work as it would restrict me to one primary and one non-primary contact - any attempt to add a third contact would fail. But I can't help feeling there would be a way to configure a unique index that gives me the minimum functionality I require - to reject an attempt to add a second primary contact, or reject an attempt to leave a company with no primary contact.

I am aware that I could just add a `primary_contact` field to the `companies` table with an FK to the `contacts` table but it feels messy. I don't like the idea of both tables having an FK to the other - it seems to me that the one table should rely on the other, not both tables relying on each other. I guess I just think that over time there is more chance of something going wrong.

To sum up:

- How can I restrict the contacts table so that one and only one record with a given `company_id` has the `is_primary` flag set?
- Anyone have any thoughts on whether two tables having FKs to each other is a good/bad idea?

Comment: I 'd take the mutual FK approach here. Obviously you cannot make both of those `NOT NULL` since then you have a chicken-and-egg problem, but making the `primary_contact` nullable both solves that and also precisely models your existing situation (there might be no primary contact for a company). Disagree that this feels messy -- if there's a 1-to-(0 or 1) relation like here, it's perfectly natural.

Comment: @Jon Sorry maybe I wasn't quite clear enough, I need to avoid a `NULL` primary contact, as it screws up one of my queries - I have a query to list all companies on one page, and as part of that I `join contacts on contacts.company_id = companies.id` and have a `where contacts.is_primary = 1` in it. So it there is no primary contact, I get no company record, and if there is more that one I get more than one. I'm actually not bothered about making the limitation rely on both tables, I just want the contacts table to verify that one contact record is always set to primary.

Comment: Circular references between tables are messy, at least.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from company to primary contact is the correct and easy way to do that. Will return exactly one row per company, and you can tell if there is a primary contact defined by checking if `primary_contact == NULL`.

Comment: @Jon Very good point about the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, I really must re-read about all the different `JOIN`s (again) - every time I do it I think I have understood it then I try and put it into practice and I always seem to get it wrong. Although I like the look of @ypercube's answer because it does actually place a restriction on what can be done. I would like if possible to design the database in such a way that it counters my/other developers ignorance when working with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular refenences between tables are indeed messy. See this (decade old) article: [SQL By Design: The Circular Reference](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/quering/sql-by-design-the-circular-reference)

The cleanest way to make such a constraint is to add another table:

```
Company_PrimaryContact
----------------------
company_id
contact_id
PRIMARY KEY (company_id)
FOREIGN KEY (company_id, contact_id)
  REFERENCES Contact (company_id, id)
```

This will also require a `UNIQUE` constraint in table `Contact` on `(company_id, id)`

Comment: Seems like this is probably a good option - may I ask what the `REFERENCES Contact (company_id, id)` part means/does? My SQL-fu is not great, I will be the first to admit...

Comment: It means that you can't add a `(company_id, contact_id)` in the `Company_PrimaryContact` table, unless a row with same values exists in the `Contact` table. So, it enforces that a PrimaryContact of a Company is indeed a Contact of this Company.

Comment: The Primary key enforces that a company can have at most one PrimaryContact.

Comment: Neat, I have never seen that before. I have just done some very interesting reading on the MySQL `FOREIGN KEY` [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and it serves exactly the purpose I require. Many thanks!

Comment: Note that you can't have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints with MyISAM or MEMORY tables. You'll need a transactional engine, like InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do a query before that one setting

```
UPDATE contacts SET is_primary = 0 WHERE company_id = .....
```

or even

```
UPDATE contacts
SET is_primary = IF(id=[USERID],1,0)
WHERE company_id = (
    SELECT company_id FROM contacts WHERE id = [USERID]
);
```

Just putting an alternative out there - personally I'd probably look to the FK approach though instead of this type of workaround i.e. have a field in the companies table with a primary_user_id field.

**EDIT** method w/o relying on a contact.is_primary field

Alternative method, first of all remove is_primary from contacts.  Secondly add a "primary_contact_id" INT field into companies.  Thirdly, when changing the primary contact, just change that primary_contact_id thus preventing any possibility of there being more than 1 primary contact at any time and all without the need for triggers etc in the background.

This option would work fine in any engine as it's simply updating an INT field, any reliance on FK's etc could be added/removed as required but at it's simplest it's just changing an INT fields value

This option is viable as long as you need one and precisely one link from companies to contacts flagging a primary

Comment: I had considered the first option and discarded it because it is susceptible to concurrency problems (two clients set two contacts to primary at the same time then you get client 1->clear primary, client 2->clear primary, client 1->set primary, client 2->set primary and you end up with two primaries) but the second idea looks interesting - I'm not sure if this would still be susceptible to it though, I think it would be alright with MyISAM but not InnoDB (which I am using)?

Comment: Will add in some info for the FK approach

Comment: +1 for a good, sensible and well explained answer, but I think I'm going to go with ypercube's because it fits better with my requirements and my existing application logic.

Comment: In fairness, ypercube's would be the option I'd go with also as while mine was rather more basic, his seperates the link from the company information which is more flexible down the line in case you wish to add multiple primary contacts